# Through list View Show Image and name of image

Tags: react-native

I want to show multiple images using listView.
I tried many time through listview, but is showing show only text.

Here's the code

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    this.state = {
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(['./flag/f1.jpg', 'England']),
    };
  }
```

Here is the issue: I have 5 flag pics and i want to give the 5 source of pic  but here I have only one datasource.
Can anyone tell me how I give the multiple source of image?

```
  render() {
    return (
      <ListView
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}

        renderRow={(rowData) => <Text>{rowData}</Text>}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your datasource has to be more complex for this, example:

```
dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows([{
   image: './flag/f1.jpg',
   name: 'England'
}, {
   image: './flag/f2.jpg',
   name: 'Germany'
}])
```

Then you can access the data like this:

```
<ListView
    dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
    renderRow={(rowData) => (
        <View>
            <Image source={{ uri: rowData.image }}/>
            <Text>{rowData.name}</Text>
        </View>
    )}
/>
```